# What is the most efficient way to represent an directed dynamic massive 3D graph?

Tags: multidimensional-array, graph-theory

I know that there are [many techniques to represent graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33592816/159072).

Suppose I have a directed massive 3D graph with 100,000 nodes at maximum.

Suppose the graph looks somewhat like the following:

[image]

Suppose each node of the graph has three pieces of information:

1. A 30-character string as a label
2. floating point values as coordinates
3. three integer values

The graph is dynamic. I.e., connections frequently change, and the nodes frequently change their coordinates.

What would be the most efficient way to represent this graph in computer memory so that I can apply mathematical operations on each node?

Should I use data structures, or should I use big-data analytics or ML?

Comment: This question is not very well-posed. Some examples: 1. What is a big data technique that is not a data structure? 2. 100k nodes is not very big unless you're in a special environment like and embedded system. 3. It's impossible to choose a good data structure without a spec for exactly the operations that need to be carried out on it. "Change connections" is not that. 4. Define "efficient." Max op latency? Amortized latency? Memory footprint?

Comment: @Gene,   *3. It's impossible to choose a good data structure without a spec for exactly the operations that need to be carried out on it. "Change connections" is not that.* --- it will be about molecular modeling and simulation.

Comment: @Gene, *2. 100k nodes are not very big unless you're in a special environment like an embedded system.* --- this would be run on a laptop with 16GB RAM and 4 core Intel CPU.

Comment: @Gene, *1. What is a big data technique that is not a data structure?* --- E.g., deep learning.

Comment: @user366312 I don't think your question is detailed enough to get a good answer. Could you add details on: how dense the graph is (ratio of edges to pairs of nodes), whether there's any relationship between edges & distance, what kind of operations or queries you want to apply to the graph? If you're free to do so, stating exactly what this graph represents and how you'll be using it might also help.